# json Array Parsing using Gson

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

i have the following Json Response as :

{"StatusCode":2,"Error_fields":[{"user":"XXX"},{"password":"YYY"}]}, and i have to parse that response using Gson, so i have built the ResponseBase class as following :

BaseResponse.java

```
    @SerializedName("StatusCode")
    private int StatusCode;

    @SerializedName("Error_fields")
    List<ErrorField> Erro;

    public void setStatusCode(int statusCode){
        this.StatusCode=statusCode;
    }

    public int getStatusCode(){
        return this.StatusCode;
    }

    public List <ErrorField> getErro() {
        return Erro;
    }

    public void setErro(List <ErrorField> erro) {
        Erro = erro;
    }
```

and Also i have added the Error Fields as :
ErrorField.java

```
public class ErrorField {

    String ErrorTitle;

    String ErrorMessage;

    public String getErrorTitle() {
        return ErrorTitle;
    }

    public void setErrorTitle(String errorTitle) {
        ErrorTitle = errorTitle;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return ErrorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

so in order , to receive the json array correctly , i have to add annotation to ErrorTitle to be :

```
@SerializedName("password")
    String ErrorTitle;
```

so in case of i don't know the returned json object key's it will fail , and it's not a good solution to add all the suggested annotation to expect is it existed or not , also i have tried to make that `List<ErrorField>` as `List<JsonObject>` and the same results it returns empty value , but it counts "2" as the Array size !?

Comment: your errors look like map more than objects

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for your answer , but i have tried that before and i got the JsonSyntaxException which is the same when i change the List to JsonArray

Comment: Hi i got what you mean , i don't understand it on the first time , but now i have changed that into     List<Map<String,String>> Errro; and it works , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by changing the `List<ErroField>` into

```
List<Map<String,String>> Errro;
```

and it's working with a dynamic range of returned json objects without depend on the key's